# How to solve the problem of showing save screen on C# word?

Tags: c#, cpu-word

I have a problem with using C# and Word application. After starting this code the document isnt saved by the written path and system shows save screen. Message box write: "Command error". Visiual Studio doesn't say about mistakes on code.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object oEndOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
        object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        Word.Application oWord = new Word.Application();
        Word.Document oDoc = new Word.Document();
        oWord.Visible = false;
        object oTemplate = @"C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Документ1.docx";
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oTemplate, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
        try
        {
            Object path1 = @"C:\Users\Владимир\Documents\Док1.doc";
            oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(path1);
            oWord.ActiveDocument.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            oWord.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code itself looks correct.  Are you sure that you have permissions to write to that folder?

Comment: Well, I didnt think about, because with .txt it works without any problems

Comment: Try saving as docx not doc

Comment: it doesnt work( Maybe the problem in Word settings. Tommorow will try programm on another computer.

Comment: I found out that problem was in my Word version (2010). Thank you that you spent time trying to help me